# Map subdomains to local IP address AND being reachable from the Internet

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, debian, bind

I would like to do a mapping between subdomains and my VMs local IP addresses.
Something that looks like this [schema](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/880945braindeadvms.png)

I've set up my DNS directly on my server (**myserver.com** for the example) and I thought that configuring my zones to something like this would have been enough but it isn't:

vm0 IN A 192.168.0.1
vm1 IN A 192.168.0.42
vm2 IN A 192.168.0.2

Of course it doesn't work, because my DNS resolves `vm0.myserver.com` by `192.168.0.1` which is only available on my dedicated server local network.

So, my question is:
**How can I make this *binding* work throughout the Internet**

Important NB:
I **don't** want :80 traffic only. I want to have access to the entire VM networks. So `nginx` reverse proxy stuffs aren't what I need or it might be enough but I didn't find how ?

By the way, I have some IPv6 addresses available but I don't want to use them, it has to be possible to do this with the old v4 protocol but I'm not good enough to make it work properly.

Thanks :)

Comment: The more I try to find a solution to this, the more I think there is just none.

Comment: @MadHatter Ok thanks. So, IPv6 it is!

Comment: The answer can be helpful for others (like me) who spent hours trying to find a solution :p

Comment: It's not possible. You really need to use IPv6 for this. (And many other reasons...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Private addresses are just that: private. If you want full routed access to all your VMs from anywhere on the internet, you need more real IP addresses, and if you want it via ipv4, you need more ipv4 addresses. Talk to your provider.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by MadHatter, you cannot do this with private IP addresses. Assuming this is from a home connection, your ISP would need to allocate public IP addresses to you using framed routing, and you would require the appropriate hardware on your end to manage this. Doing this also opens up a lot of security issues, so that is another thing to consider.